# Cross-platform library for communications between C++ and platform-native code (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, cross-platform

I know this had been asked many times already, but I could not find anything close to what I want among existing SO answers.

Basically, we're about to create complicated mobile application which will have following features:

- 3D graphics rendering with OpenGL
- Integration with camera, accelerometer, gyroscope and other hardware functions
- Working with network (HTTP)
- Local database (SQLite)
- Hard drive usage
- zip-files and encryption (OpenSSL)
- Integration with 3rd party hardware (e.g. a 3rd party sensor attached to tablet) with their own SDKs

We want this app to work in iOS, Android and Windows environment. Many solutions are considered, including Qt, Xamarin and others, but it's seems quite risky to use these frameworks in such a complicated usecase.

What we now have in mind is building each app natively, but maintaining as much shared code as possible in shared C++ libraries.

For example, we'd like to make C++ components for various features, like:

- HTTP communication with server
- File encryption
- Business logic
- ...

However, there is a certain problem. It's not clear, how do we connect native UI layer and C++ code in libraries.
It's easy to call library functions from Java or Obj-C code, but many of them will invoke some asynchronous tasks (call HTTP url, dump file to disk). It's not clear how to propagate results of such asynchronous tasks back to UI code.

What we ideally want to have is some MvvM architecture where Views are completely platform-specific, but Models and partially ViewModels are written in C++. Also, such architectures often utilize "Services" - those could also have platform-specific interface, but C++ core.

Is there a known way to provide such integration? Maybe there is library that provides "middle layer" between UI code and libraries?

Or maybe our approach is not viable at all, what would you suggest in this case?

Comment: I'm confused by your description of what you think is hard. If you can call a function easily, you can receive a result from that function just as easily. Can you spend a little more time defining exactly what it is you're looking for?

Comment: Research "Interface description language" and their support

Comment: I added some clarifications. Obviously it is possible to obtain the return value of synchronous function call, but this covers only a fraction of usecases. Note how we usually code the apps: call some async method, wait until callback or continuation is invoked, update UI accordingly. One can write some wrappers for each platform to do these async C++ calls, but I was asking for some known solution that resolves that.

Comment: Quite a valid question; the author is primarily asking about the viability of the approach, not for just a library. Looks like SO needs to revise some of its policies regarding off-topic questions.